# forming words combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many five-letter words can you form with the letters a, b, c, and d if two of these letters should occur exactly twice?

I thought:

we first choose the two letters:

- (4 nCr 2)

then we choose the positions for these letters:

- (5 nCr 2) * (3 nCr 2)

then we have one position left for one letter to choose out of 2:

- 2

so: (4 nCr 2) * (5 nCr 2) * (3 nCr 2) * 2

Can someone please confirm this solution/explain why this solution is incorrect?

Comment: it is right , good work !